django took too long to shut down and was killed
I am using Django Channel for a real-time sending and saving data but when I refresh the page the error came up. I don't know why but, on first load the system is okay but if I reload the page the log appears.
Application instance <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at /home/planet/Dhruvil/DRF/websoket/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<_GatheringFuture pending cb=[Task.task_wakeup()]>> for connection <WebRequest at 0x7f2535d4d7e0 method=GET uri=/stock-info/?symbol=SBIN clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to shut down and was killed.
The above exception occurs and the entire service stops running.
how i solve this error.
consumers.py
class StockInfoConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = 'stock_consumer'
        self.room_group_name = 'stock_updates'
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.close()
        raise StopConsumer()

    async def send_stock_info(self, event):
        stock_info = json.loads(event.get('stock_info'))
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'payload' : stock_info}))

views.py
def get_one_stock_info(symbol):
    stock_info = {}
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
    baseurl = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/"
    url = f"https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/{symbol}.NS"
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(baseurl, headers=headers, timeout=5)
    cookies = dict(request.cookies)
    
    while True:
        response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5, cookies=cookies)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                data = response.json()
                stock_info['Symbol'] = symbol
                stock_info['Price'] = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketPrice']
                stock_info['High'] = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketDayHigh'] 
                stock_info['Low'] = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketDayLow']
                stock_info['Volume'] = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['regularMarketVolume']
                stock_info['PreviousClose'] = data['chart']['result'][0]['meta']['previousClose']
                return stock_info
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"Error fetching data. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        
        time.sleep(0.0001)

        return stock_info



class OneStockInfoAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        symbol = request.query_params.get('symbol')
        if not symbol:
            return Response({'error': 'symbol parameter is required'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        while True:
            stock_info = get_one_stock_info(symbol)

            # Send stock info over WebSocket
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                'stock_updates',  # Group name
                {
                    'type': 'send_stock_info',
                    'stock_info': json.dumps(stock_info),
                }
            )
            time.sleep(1)

StockInfo.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const StockInfo = () => {
  const [stockData, setStockData] = useState(null);
  const [ws, setWs] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch stock data from REST API
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/stock-info/?symbol=SBIN')
      .then(response => {
        setStockData(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching stock data:', error);
      });

    // Connect to WebSocket for live updates
    const newWs = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/stock-info/');
    newWs.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connection opened');
    };
    newWs.onmessage = (event) => {
      const newData = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log('Received new stock data:', newData);
      setStockData(newData.payload);
    };
    newWs.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };

    setWs(newWs);

    return () => {
      console.log('Closing WebSocket connection');
      newWs.close();
    };
  }, []);

  const handlePageUnload = () => {
    if (ws) {
      console.log('Closing WebSocket connection on page unload');
      ws.close();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handlePageUnload);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handlePageUnload);
    };
  }, [ws]);

  const getPriceColor = () => {
    if (!stockData) return ''; // Default color if data is not yet loaded
    return stockData.Price < stockData.PreviousClose ? 'red' : 'green';
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <h1>Live Stock Data</h1>
        {stockData && (
          <div>
            <p>Symbol: {stockData.Symbol}</p>
            <p style={{ color: getPriceColor() }}>Price: {stockData.Price}</p>
            <p>High: {stockData.High}</p>
            <p>Low: {stockData.Low}</p>
            <p>Volume: {stockData.Volume}</p>
            <p>Previous Close: {stockData.PreviousClose}</p>
            {/* Add more data fields as needed */}
          </div>
        )}
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StockInfo;


Possibly due to some ongoing processes or tasks. In such cases, the system may automatically kill the application to free up resources. To prevent this from happening in the future, you can try optimising your code, closing any open connections or processes, and handling shutdown tasks efficiently.
